# Azure Sentinel, Analytics Rule 14 days lookback limit

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

When writing log analytics rule it has an option for a lookback time period which is 14 days maximum. However, I am writing queries/rules that are correlating historical data for last 30 days and because of this limit, I am missing some potential matches.

Is there a way to increase the 14-day lookback limit or workarounds to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you pls offer the doc link which said the lookback time period is 14 days maximum? I may misunderstand some place as I remembered that the query time range is more than 14 days.

Comment: In log analytics, the time range can be whatever we want but I was talking about "analytics rules"/ "query scheduling" where the lookback time range is 14 days maximum regardless of the time range defined in the query. here's the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/tutorial-detect-threats-custom#query-scheduling-and-alert-threshold

Comment: I haven't found any solution to it until now : (  The field has rules to forbid the period bigger than 14 days and after setting up the rule, there's also no other place such as manifest file to change the period.